error where the notification is remove success but the data in the backend fails remove
I don't know, why is the error where the notification status remove success but the data in the backend failed. (my frontend use react inertia js and backend use express js).
My Frontend
this my code controller in react inertia js
 public function getToken(Request $request)
    {
        $accessToken = $request->session()->get('access_token');
        if (!$accessToken) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized Token'], 403);
        }
        return $accessToken;
    }

    public function deleteFavorites(Request $request, $id)
    {
        try {
            $token = $this->getToken($request);
            if (!$token) return redirect()->route('login');

            $response = Http::withHeaders([
                'Authorization' => "Bearer {$token} ",
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ])->delete("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/favorites", [
                'productId' => $id
            ]);

            if (!$response->successful()) {
                Log::error('Failed to delete favorite', [
                    'status' => $response->status(),
                    'body' => $response->body()
                ]);
                return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Failed to delete from favorites');
            }

            return redirect()->route('favorites.index')
                ->with('success', 'Item successfully removed from favorites');

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Error in deleteFavorites:', ['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Failed to delete favorite');
        }
    }

this my code favorite page in react inertia js
router.delete(`/favorites/${id}`, {
        preserveState: true,
        preserveScroll: true,
        onSuccess: (page) => {
            // Only updates if the response from the server is different
            if (page.favorites) {
                setFavorites(page.favorites);
            }

            toast.success('Item removed from favorites')
            setIsLoading(false)
            toast.dismiss(loadingToast)
            console.log('Current favorites before deletion:', favorites) //test in inspect
            console.log('ID to delete:', id) // test in inspect

        },
        onError: (errors) => {
            // Rollback state if failed
            if (auth?.favorites) {
                setFavorites(auth.favorites);
            }

            console.error('Delete error:', errors);
            toast.dismiss(loadingToast);
            toast.error(errors.error || 'Failed to remove item');
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
    })
}

**My Backend
**
this is my code controller in express js
export const removeFromFavorites = async (req, res) => {
  const userId = jwt.decode(req.headers["authorization"].split(" ")[1]).id;
  const { productId } = req.body;
  try {
    const favoriteExists = await prisma.favorite.findFirst({
      where: {
        user_id: userId,
        product_id: productId,
      },
    })

    if (!favoriteExists) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Product not found in favorites" });
    }

    await prisma.favorite.deleteMany({
      where: {
        user_id: userId,
        product_id: productId,
      },
    });
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Product removed from favorites" });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error removing from favorites", error });
  }
}

The Output:

